# display alternate url after redirect using $base_url

Tags: 8, configuration, uri

1) have 2 d8 sites: `site1.com` and `subd.site2.com` in a multisite server (no root access)
  2) would like `site1.com/subd` to redirect to `subd.site2.com` BUT display url `site1.com/subd` 
  3) I now have an `.htaccess` redirect

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^site1.com$ [NC]
      RewriteRule ^/subd/(.*) http://subd.site2.com/$1 [P,L]

4) `site1.com/subd` NOW redirects to `subd.site2.com` but displays `subd.site2.com`
  5) when inserting `$base_url = 'http://site1.com/subd'` in `settings.php`get server error

Comment: The ability to override the `$base_url` has been removed in D8. More info here but I haven't found a solution yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180391/drupal-8-nginx-reverse-proxy-as-subdir